# Multi-Processing browser?

Tags: c++, windows, browser, multiprocessing, inter-process-communicat

I want to know what framework/Interface/API's Set is best to use to create multi-process browser, i want to be able to use UDP/TCP for the process-to-process communication.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to leverage WebKit2. It was designed from the ground up for sandboxed/multi-process support.

http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebKit2

Comment: Is it possible to use TCP/UDP for the inter process communication ? i think no...

Comment: Why is that relevant? Anyway, I don't think it works that way today, but obviously it's open source so you can make it do whatever you want.

Comment: Using MS IWebBrowser Interface not possible to create multi-processing browser using TCP for IPC?

Comment: I Found this -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752047(v=vs.85).aspx but i am not sure if thats what i am looking for....

Comment: Internet Explorer is a monolithic process that runs in-app.